# Milnor's proof of Homogeneity lemma

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-topology

I was reading Milnor's topology from the differential  point of view.page 24

In the Homogeneity lemma,which state that for any two interiror point  $y,z$ of smooth connected manifold $N$,exist a diffeomorphism $h:N\to N$ that is smooth isotopic to identity and carries $y$ to $z$.

He prove it as follows:

- for $N = S^{n-1}$ the result clear
- construct a smooth diffeomorphism $F_t$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$ to itself,such that carries origin to any point inside open disk,nad $F_t$ isotopic to identity map.

Finally we need to complete the proof.I don't know how to use the 2 facts above to complete the proof?

Comment: A small regular neigbourhood of an injective path (i.e. diffeormphic to [0,1]) between these two points is diffeomorphic to a ball.

Comment: @Thomas thanks,it seems something that I haven't learnt

Comment: @Thomas can you provide some reference?

Comment: No, but I can alos give you a second proof. Fix x, the set of points y wihc satisfies your propertyu is certainly open and close, so this is the manifold itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x\in N$, conisder $N_x=\{y:f(x)=y$ and $f$ is isotopy to the identity $\}$.

We are going to show that $N_x$ is open and closed. Let $y\in N_x$ there exists a diffeomorphism $f_y$ connected to the identity such that $f_y(x)=y$. There exists a chart $U_y$ of $N$ containing $y$ which is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$. This implies that for every $z\in U_y$, there exists $g_z$ isotopy to the identity, $g_z(y)=z$. $g_z\circ f_y(x)=z$ and is isotopic to the identity. This implies that $N_x$ is open. $N_x$ is closed, if $y=limy_n, y\in N_x$, there exists a neighborhood $U_y$ diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$ which contains $y_n$. We deduce that there exists a diffeomorphism $h_n$ isotopic to the identity such that $h_n(y_n)=y$, if $f_n$ is a diffeomorphism isotopic to the identity such that $f_n(x)=y_n$, $h_n\circ f_n$ is isomorphic to the identity. We deduce that $N_x$ is closed.

Comment: Hi the construction of $g_z$ used to prove the open is based on the diffeomorphism given in the previous step on the open disk ,correct ?that is first using the chart map ,maps $y,z\in N$ to $\bar{y},\bar{z}\in \mathbb{R}^n$.then exist $\bar{g}_z :\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ maps $\bar{y} \to \bar{z}$?

Comment: Exactly it is based on that.

Comment: thanks,there is another elementary question :there exist a neiborhood at each point $y\in N$ such that homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$ since,first we know the basis on the manifold can be coordinate ball,that  exist homeomorphism to a open ball in $\mathbb{R}^n$ then we know the open ball homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$,hence we have the existence of the neiborhood homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$ correct?

Comment: Yes it is correct.

Comment: There is another question that is why construct the flow only on the open disk,it seems if we define the non zero flow on the whole $\mathbb{R}^n$ is ok?

Comment: We can suppose that the open neighborhood is diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: But define the $\varphi(x) >0$ on whole $\mathbb{R}^n$ seems more direct?why first truncate the $\varphi$ inside disk then diffeomorphic the point inside the disk to $\mathbb{R}^n$

Comment: Thanks I have found the statement in Lee's smooth manifold book theorem 9.16,which says Every  compactly supported smooth vector field is complete