# Understanding Milnor's Homogeneity lemma proof

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-topology

In chapter 4 of Milnor's *Topology from the Differentiable Viewpoint* it is proved the following lemma:

> **Homogeneity Lemma.** Let $y$ and $z$ be arbitrary interior points of the smooth, connected manifold $N$. Then there exists a diffeomorphism $h: N \to N$ that is smoothly isotopic to the identity and carries $y$ to $z$.

In this question, I will denote $x \sim y$ if such a diffeomorphism $h$ exists. It's proof, as is pointed out in [this math.se question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3917880/milnors-proof-of-homogeneity-lemma), construct a smooth diffeomorphism $F_t: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ that carries the origin to any point in the open disk, with $F_t$ being isotopic to the identity.

It is stated that, given $y \in \mathbb{R}^n$, this diffeomorphism ensures the existence of an open neighborhood $V$ of $y$ such that $x \sim y, \ \forall x \in V$. My question is: How come this diffeomorphism ensures the existence of such a neighborhood?

Comment: Is it $y\in \mathbb R^n$ or $y\in N$?

Comment: $y \in \mathbb{R}^n$. If I understand it correctly, the result is shown for $\mathbb{R}^n$, then the result follows locally. The conclusion follows, as $N$ is connected.

Comment: You already pointed out that you can reach any point in the open unit disc around the origin via an isotopy. By shifting everything to a fixed $y$, we get $x ~ y$ for any $x$ in the open unit disc around $y$. That open disc is your desired neighborhood.